# Excel: How to change a value and then update based on that new value without having a circular reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

**A fundamental stock management question (I believe)**

In simple terms:

```
IF(A<=0,A=20,)
```

Of course, it doesn't work because the moment you add 20, 'A' becomes positive.
Excel recalculates and 20 is removed.
Excel recalculates and 20 is added, etc........

We need a way to make A=+20 .... then look at B,C,D for the next negative condition.

Almost all business models must cope with stock replenishment.
... but how has this been achieved?

Here is the link to Google sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/121LsvpK3GrVHVAgIK7npTX3-N9P5LOZZLZIenqeEj9s/edit?usp=sharing

*Below simply lists the above spreadsheet in text.
There will be other variables to consider, but the fundamental problem first needs to be answered*

---

**Here is the fundamental stock problem explained:**

We have sales, stock balance, and the delivery requirement (to coincide with the lack of stock).

- The starting stock is entered.
- The projected sales per week are entered.
- At a certain week, all the stock is sold.
- At that week, a delivery of stock must occur.

Manually, this is very easy to deal with ... we look for a projected negative (or zero) stock balance, and we tap the keyboard and enter the required stock delivery.
We scroll through the stock level – find the next week where stock is needed, and the delivery requirement is entered.

Fine.

Only that if the projected sales are changed, all the delivery dates must change.

This would mean, once again, manually changing the first negative stock level, and again looking for the next negative stock level, etc.

**However...**
Financial models need to work, simply by changing the projected sales.

Load the sales projection, find the week with no stock, add a delivery.... then find the next week with no stock.

The only human intervention is to change the sales figures.

---

Here is a very simple version:

```
         A               B             C          D          E          F          G          H          I
  +---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
1 |  01/03/2017   |     Date      | 05/03/17 | 12/03/17 | 19/03/17 | 26/03/17 | 02/04/17 | 09/04/17 | 16/04/17 |
  +---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
2 | Stock         | Delivery      |        1 |          |          |          |          |          |          |
3 |               | Consignment   |       37 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
4 |               | Stock Balance |       22 |       11 |       -1 |       -1 |       -1 |       -1 |       -1 |
5 |               | Sales         |       15 |       11 |       12 |          |          |          |          |
6 | Order Qty Ref | Item qty      |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |
  +---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

`C2:I2` = A number 1 to 7

`C3:I3` = Monitors `C2:I2` for numbers 1 to 7 then searches the 'Order Qty Ref' Range (in Row 6) and posts the 'item qty', e.g., 37
        i.e., if delivery = 1 ..... 37 is the consignment.

=
IF(C2=1,$C$6,
IF(C2=2,$D$6,
IF(C2=3,$E$6,
IF(C2=4,$F$6,
IF(C2=5,$G$6,
IF(C2=6,$H$6,
IF(C2=7,$I$6,
)))))))

`C4` = `C3-C5` ..... This simply opens the stock balance - Consignment-Sales.

`D4:I4` = `C4+D3-D5` ..... Each cell adds the previous stock balance to any new consignment, and subtracts any sales.

`C5:I5` = A number representing number of units sold (in the model this range of sales numbers is chosen by a drop list).

`C6:I6` = A separate range of 7 potential deliveries of stock.

The model starting position has the sales projections loaded, and the first consignment (1).

Manually we would look for the first 0 or negative stock balance (Row 4) – we find the first one in Column `E`, and add a 1 (or a number between 1 & 7) in Row 2 (i.e., in cell `E2`).

```
+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  01/03/2017   |     Date      | 05/03/17 | 12/03/17 | 19/03/17 | 26/03/17 | 02/04/17 | 09/04/17 | 16/04/17 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Stock         | Delivery      |        1 |          |    →   1 |          |          |          |          |
|               | Consignment   |       37 |        0 |       37 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|               | Stock Balance |       22 |       11 |       35 |       20 |        9 |       -4 |      -19 |
|               | Sales         |       15 |       11 |       13 |       15 |       11 |       13 |       15 |
| Order Qty Ref | Item qty      |       37 |       74 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

We then manually look for the next zero or negative stock balance (finding it in cell `H4`), and add another 1 (in cell `H2`).

```
+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  01/03/2017   |     Date      | 05/03/17 | 12/03/17 | 19/03/17 | 26/03/17 | 02/04/17 | 09/04/17 | 16/04/17 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Stock         | Delivery      |        1 |          |        1 |          |          |    →   1 |          |
|               | Consignment   |       37 |        0 |       37 |        0 |        0 |       37 |        0 |
|               | Stock Balance |       22 |       11 |       35 |       20 |        9 |       33 |       18 |
|               | Sales         |       15 |       11 |       13 |       15 |       11 |       13 |       15 |
| Order Qty Ref | Item qty      |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |       37 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Okay, easy - the simple calculation is:
IF (Stock_balance<=0,Delivery=1,)

The problem is that, the moment the stock balance is adjusted to positive.... Excel removes the 1 ... leaving the stock balance negative – ad infinitum (circular reference error).

---

Clearly, we need Excel to calculate 'left to right' each cell, until a zero, or negative condition is met.
Enter the stock delivery... then re-start calculations from the first cell, until a zero or negative condition is met.

In effect, we need Excel to imitate human intervention.

E.g.,

```
IF(Stock_balance<=0,Delivery=1[stop_recalculate_until_no_negatives_are_found],)
```

---

It's all been done before, but I can't find the solution via search.
Therefore I believe this question is ideal for Super User.

Comment: I might be able to help you, but I cannot understand your problem. It might help if you posted some sample data, including relevant formulas that you currently have, and then show by example what you want to happen. [Please don’t post images of text.](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408) Post a textual representation of the data, as was done [here](/q/889201/150988) and [here](/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) site if you want.

Comment: Thanks Scott... I've edited the question and uploaded a simple spreadsheet... so I await in anticipation :)

Comment: I’m a little paranoid about downloading files from people I don’t know. I’m relying entirely on your revised question.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the real-world scenario 100%, but I believe that I’m getting a grip on the mathematics.  Let me give an overview of the problem as I see it: Row 1 is basically just decoration; the dates label the columns, but they don’t play a role in the calculations.  Rows 5 and 6 are given as input.  Values in Row 3 are trivially computed from the values above them, in Row 2.  Then values in Row 4 are computed from values in the other rows.  The gotcha is that, moving from left to right, you use the values in Row 4 to decide the values in Row 2. Let me know if I’ve got that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,
I can offer a much more concise form of the formula for Row 3
and an alternative form for Row 4
(one that doesn’t need to make `C4` a special case):

- Row 3 → `=IF(C$2=0, 0, INDEX($C$6, 1, C$2))`
  This is simple — if `C2` is 0, `C3` is zero. 
  (Remember that blank tests as equal to zero.) 
  Otherwise, use the number from `$C$6`, `$D$6`, `$E$6`, …, indexed by `C2`.
- Row 4 → `=SUM($C3:C3)-SUM($C5:C5)`
  ***In*** cell `C4`, this reduces to `C3-C5`. 
  As you drag/fill it to the right,
  the first cell in each range remains anchored in Column `C`
  while the second cell automatically increases.
  So `D4` is `=SUM(C3:D3)-SUM(C5:D5)`, `E4` is `=SUM(C3:E3)-SUM(C5:E5)`, etc.

The problem is that you want to choose the value in Row 2
based on the value in Row 4
***before applying*** the values in Rows 2 and 3
to the value in Row 4 for the current column —
and so you’ve been getting a circular reference. 
The solution is to establish a “helper row”
that computes precisely this phantom value
(the value in Row 4 before applying the values in Rows 2 and 3). 
For example, I’ve put it into Row 9<sup>†</sup> :

- `C9` → `=-C5`
- `D9` → `=SUM($C3:C3)-SUM($C5:D5)` (and drag/fill this to the right).

You can see that this equals the value in Row 4
before the value in Row 3 has been added. 
It’s then a simple matter of setting Row 2 to `=IF(C9<=0, 1, 0)`
(which is a formula you already have)
and format the cells not to display zeroes. 
(Or you can make the formula `=IF(C9<=0, 1, "")` if you prefer.) 
Now you can change the projected sales (in Row 5)
and the delivery schedule in Rows 2 and 3 will update automatically.

[image: spreadsheet]

I changed the format of your dates because I write dates as mm/dd/yy
(yeah, I know it’s irrational, but it’s a cultural thing),
and looking at dates formatted as dd/mm/yy hurts my eyes.
________
<sup>†</sup>  Of course you can put the helper row wherever you want,
such as Row 99, or on another sheet,
and you can hide it once you have everything working. 
Or we could remove the helper row altogether,
at the cost of making the Row 2 formula much more complex.

Comment: Thank you Scott, your answer is the final piece in the jigsaw that makes the entire model work. The whole spreadsheet now changes by simply loading a different 'sales range'... I am so grateful for your help... I can't upvote it, but perhaps others will. *NOTE* Edit req. INDEX($C$6*:$I$6*, ... I now need to work on a concept to switch in different 'delivery' numbers while keeping the previous delivery numbers in situ. - simply ascending the numbers 1, 2, 3... will be ideal... Thanks also for improving my formulas - INDEX is very good :)

Comment: Hmm!... it's quite tricky to get the delivery number to increment... perhaps I should be looking at another helper row.

Comment: Yes... the helper row solved the problem quickly... I added a row 8... the opening delivery number C8 is manually entered (we know the 1st delivery date so the 1 will be present in all calculations)... D8 [=IF(D9>=1, C8, 1+C8)] ... therefore C8:I8 is populated with 1's until the next delivery, which subsequently populates the row with 2's... C2 simply copies C8 [=IF(C9<=0, C8, 0)]... Now, the individual delivery data can be modified from a reference table eg. C6:I6 ... this wraps up v1.0 ... I just hope my question 'title' is relevant to searches on this problem (to share the info).

Comment: RE: The title... I had let it rest... then returned to edit it and found that you'd got there first... thanks for that... I'm now in the 'wind-down' programming phase, where the mind considers how 'user-friendly / at-a-glance-understandable' is the model :)